# Need to send ASCII string from website to PC via UDP

Tags: javascript, node.js, udp, ascii

I'm looking for some ideas on how to approach this challenege.
I have a tablet that I'm using as a remote control to trigger software on a PC.
The trigger is an ASCII string that has to be sent via UDP.
The network is closed, no protection or security enabled. The server has a static IP.
I've built the website and created all the functions but haven't found a great way to actually send the text from the website to the PC.
I'm thinking that node.js -- which I have no experience with -- is the only way to do this but I'd appreciate some other thoughts.

Thanks.
Dave